# Forward específico para una parte de la página

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Alguien sabe si hay una forma de que con el `request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina.jsp).forward(request, response);`
pueda mandarme a una sección especifica? osea que en el enlace quedara algo así 
"localhost:8084/pagina#seccion3"

Answer (score 0):

No que yo sepa, porque en el **getRequestDispatcher** solo se especifica el nombre de la página a la que redireccionas.

Comment: Entonces algún otro método que pueda servir pero que igual pase los request y response?

Comment: Ni idea amigo, sigue esperando por aquí haber si alguien tiene esa respuesta.
Te recomiendo que leas un poquito de **ajax** de pronto encuentres por alguna solución con ello.